# Infinitely often zero probability implies finite maximum

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, borel-cantelli-lemmas

"For a sequence of events $\{U_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$, let ${1}_{U_n}$ be 
and indicator for $U_n$. Let $N = \text{max}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\{1_{U_n} = 1\}$. $\mathbb{P}(U_n \: i.o) = 0 
\Longleftrightarrow \mathbb{E}[N] <\infty $."

I'm not sure if this is true in either direction. I tried forward first.

Suppose $\mathbb{P}(U_n \: i.o) = 0$. By Borel-Cantelli Lemma,

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb{P}(U_n) < \infty $. Note that 
$\mathbb{P}(N = n) = \mathbb{P}(U_n)\mathbb{P}(\cap_{j=n+1}^\infty U_j^c) = \mathbb{P}(U_n)\mathbb{P}((\cup_{j=n+1}^\infty U_n)^c) = \mathbb{P}(U_n)-\mathbb{P}(U_n)\mathbb{P}(\cup_{j=n+1}^\infty U_n)$.

But then I don't know how to show that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n\mathbb{P}(N=n) < \infty$ if it is a true statement.

Comment: I think the implication $\implies$ is false. The reverse implication  is true. Just use the fact that $N <\infty$ with probbaility $1$.

Comment: Would this prove that the $\implies$ direction is false?  Pick your favorite non-negative integer R.V. $M$ where $E[M] = \infty$.  Then define the (dependent) events s.t. only $U_M$ happens, i.e. only $1_{U_M} = 1$.  Thus $N=M$ and yet only one event happens (i.e. they do not happen infinitely often).